# Caculate surface of vivianis window

Tags: analysis, surface-integrals

I want to calculate the surface of
$$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2=4 \;\wedge\; (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \}$$
My attempt: try to solve with a substitution of polar coordinates, but I have not been able to parametrize $x^2+y^2+z^2=4 \;\wedge\; (x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.

Edit: Per @Math Lover's suggestion, I tried his parametrization:
$z\in[-2,2]$ implies $z=2\cos(\phi)$ (then $\phi\in [0,\pi]$ or $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$?). Choose $y=2\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\;x=2\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)$.
$\implies 4\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)+4\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)+4\cos^2(\phi)=4$, which satisfies the first equation.
To intersect the two equations, I wrote $$(2\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)-1)^2+4\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi) \overset{!}{=} 4$$
The solutions I got from this were $$\theta=\pm \cos^{-1}\left(\sin(\phi) - \frac{1}{\sin(\phi)}\right)$$
So I have $0\leq\phi\leq\pi$ (?) and $-\cos^{-1}\left(\sin(\phi) - \frac{1}{\sin(\phi)}\right)\leq\theta\leq +\cos^{-1}\left(\sin(\phi) - \frac{1}{\sin(\phi)}\right)$.
I am now unsure what to integrate over to get the area. $z^2$? If yes, then
$\implies \int\limits_Sz^2\;do = \int\limits_{\phi=0}^\pi\int\limits_{\theta=-\cos^{-1}\left(\sin(\phi) - \frac{1}{\sin(\phi)}\right)}^{\cos^{-1}\left(\sin(\phi) - \frac{1}{\sin(\phi)}\right)}
4\cos^2(\phi) \sin(\phi) \;d\theta d\phi$
Is $\sin(\phi)$ the correct factor for this substitution? Do I need another factor like $\sqrt{2}$? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you are using spherical coordinates, parametrize as $r(\theta, \phi) = (2 \cos\theta \sin\phi, 2 \sin\theta \sin\phi, 2 \cos\phi)$. The intersection curve of sphere and cylinder is the  boundary that should give you limits of integration. Please make an attempt and post your work if you get stuck and need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks you to find surface area of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4~$ for $~(x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1$.

The parametrization for the sphere is correct. You wrote the intersection of surfaces incorrectly. The RHS should be $1$ and not $4$.

$~(x-1)^2 + y^2 \leq 1$ can be simplified as $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x$. As you can see from the equation, $x^2 + y^2 \leq 2x$ only forms for $x \geq 0$ and hence $-\pi/2 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$.

At the intersection with the surface of the sphere, $x^2 + y^2 = 4 \sin^2\phi = 2 \cdot 2 \cos\theta \sin\phi \implies \cos\theta = \sin\phi$

So if we only evaluate the surface area for $z \geq 0$ and then using symmetry, multiply by $2$ to include surface below $z \leq 0$,

$- (\pi/2 - \phi) \leq \theta \leq (\pi/2 - \phi), 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$

As we know the surface area element of sphere is $4 \sin \phi ~ d\theta ~ d\phi$ so the integral becomes,

$ \displaystyle S = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{- (\pi/2 - \phi)}^{(\pi/2 - \phi)} 4 \sin\phi ~ d\theta ~ d\phi$

or,

$ \displaystyle S = 4 \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{(\pi/2 - \theta)} 4 \sin\phi ~ d\phi ~ d\theta$

Comment: Thank you, that was very clear! Could you please just explain the change between $\theta$, $\phi$, $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ in your last line?

Comment: @stack_math again considering surface for $z \geq 0$, we have $\sin\phi \leq \cos\theta$ so if we integrate wrt $\phi$ first, we need to be aware that $\theta \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ and bounds for $\phi$ is $0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2} - {|\theta|}$. So we can multiply by two and just consider $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. That is why $4$ times $\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{(\pi/2 - \theta)} 4 \sin\phi ~ d\phi ~ d\theta$

Comment: @stack_math one more thing - you can also choose to do this in cylindrical coordinates. The integral set up is not complicated in cylindrical coordinates either.